# how to call method on a class while an event of object inside it is triggered

Tags: java, android, class, events, methods

i have a code like this, this just an example class with an object of a class with an event listener.

```
public class MyActivity ..... {

     EditText something;
     AnyFragment frag;

     public MyActivity(){
          frag = new AnyFragment();
     }


     public void setText(String text){
          something.setText(text);
     }

}

public class AnyFragment extends DialogFragment implements AnyListener{

     public void onEvent(String text){
          // How to call method setText in class MyActivity from here ?
     }

}
```

My problem is: 
how to call method setText in class MyActivity while event on frag object is triggered?

or there's another approach to do that?

Any answer would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public class MyActivity ..... {

     EditText something;
     AnyFragment frag;

     public MyActivity(){
          frag = new AnyFragment(this);
     }

     public void setText(String text){
          something.setText(text);
     }
}

public class AnyFragment extends DialogFragment implements AnyListener{

     private Context context;

     public AnyFragment(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
     }

     public void onEvent(String text){
         ((MyActivity)context).setText(text);
     }
}
```

or using an `interface`:

```
public class MyActivity ..... {

     EditText something;
     AnyFragment frag;

     public MyActivity(){
         frag = new AnyFragment();
         frag.setFragListener(new AnyFragment.FragListener() {
             @Override
             public void notifyActivity(String text) {
                 setText(text);
             }
         });
     }

     public void setText(String text){
         something.setText(text);
     }
}

public class AnyFragment extends DialogFragment implements AnyListener{

    private FragListener listener;

    public setFragListener(FragListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onEvent(String text){
        if(listener != null)
            listener.notifyActivity(text);
    }

    public interface FragListener {
        void notifyActivity(String text);
    }
}
```